# How to "maximize" Xcode debug area?

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, it is possible to bring up the "debug area" by pressing cmd-shift-Y. It only takes up half the window area usually taking up by the source code. However, you can then drag the split all the way up to take up the entire window area.

If you press cmd-shift-Y to dismiss it and then bring it back up again, it does not cover the entire window area. Any keyboard shortcut that will let you do this so that you don't have the mouse-drag it every time?